# Cannot access github releases for a repo, via web UI

Tags: github, version-control, github-release

I'm looking to test out github releases.

The [guidance](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository#creating-a-release) says:

> On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
>
> To the right of the list of files, click Releases or Latest release.

However, when I do this there is no "Releases" or "Latest release" button.

Is there some obvious configuration I need to do to the repo first?

Comment: Same problem, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on *"tag"* (you will find it at top left next to branches *or* search for it using `Ctrl-F tag`)
   *or* simply go to https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/releases.
2. Click on *"Draft a new release"*.
3. Follow the [guidance](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository#creating-a-release) from step **4**.